# pointwise convergence of semimartingales in probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

In a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.195.6584&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on stochastic finance I'm recently studying, the author defined a closure of some subspace of semimartingales by convergence in probability: $S^N_t\rightarrow S_t$ for each $t$, as $N\rightarrow\infty$, and claimed this convergence defined a metrizable topology. I am not sure how can this be. I do know UCP (uniform convergence on compacts in probability) is metrizable though. Furthermore, I wonder if $S^N$ is RCLL for each N, does the limit process $S$ have an RCLL version? The $S^N$'s are of the form $$ dS_t=S_{t_t}(a_tdt+\sigma_tdW_t+\int_E b(v,t)q(dv,dt))$$ where $W$ is browning motion, and $q$ is a compensated jump measure on a mark space $E\times[0,\infty)$, $a$, $\sigma$ and $b$ are suitably integrable. You can assume further regularities on these integrands if necessary. If these claims aren't always true, what are (some of) the conditions on the integrands such that these claims make sense? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: The limit process need not to be rcll: obviously, it is possible to construct a deterministic sequence of rcll functions whose limit is not rcll (so it does not have an rcll modification). However, when we allow only rcll limits, the convergence is metrizable (however, the space will be incomplete). What exactly is the paper you are reading?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. The paper was "A general benchmark model for stochastic jump sizes" by M.M. Christensen and E. Platen (http://www.qfrc.uts.edu.au/research/research_papers/rp139), where they defined a portfolio as in the SDE above, and a *generalized portfolio* as pointwise limit in probability of a sequence of portfolios. So if only RCLL limits are allowed, what would be a metrization? Similar to the UCP metrization with t restricted on rationals so that  the sum make sense? Any idea what conditions on the integrands that would guarantee RCLL convergence?

Comment: Ok, I see. Will write a bit later.

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote about the metrizability, I thought about something different. Unfortunately, I don't see how is it metrizable; one needs some kind of tightness of the sequence for this. However, I didn't find the place in the paper where the authors claim the metrizability. Could you clarify?

Comment: After definition 2.1, where $S_t$ is defined as an RCLL Ito process (satisfying the SDE) which is also a point-wise limit in probability of a sequence of portfolios which are stochastic integrals over finitely many primary securities, the authors claim that $S_t$ lies in a space which is the "closure of span of  all admissible portfolios in all the markets, $\mathbb{S}^N$, in a suitable topology. In this case, the metric introduced by convergence in probability is suitable as it reflects what one is able to approximate in a path-wise sense. "

Comment: Probably, you have another version of this paper, because under the link there is no such phrase. Definition 2.1 is followed by Section 2.4.

Comment: I have updated the link to the paper. I apologize for the confusion, the version hosted by UTS seems an earlier one. By the way, thank you very much for your careful readings and answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29085/discussion-between-user138668-and-zhoraster).